# Why aren't my SQL placeholders being replaced (using Go pq)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

As per the docs, I'm doing this

```
var thingname string = "asdf";
var id int
err = database.QueryRow("SELECT id from things where thing = ?", thingname).Scan(&id)
```

but Postgres is saying

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input at character 41
STATEMENT:  SELECT id from things where thing = ?
```

I can't see that I'm doing much different to the demo code. I'm using [pq](http://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact syntax is database dependent.

Use

```
err = database.QueryRow("SELECT id from things where thing = $1", thingname).Scan(&id)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Can you point me toward documentation for this? I did a quick search and was unable to find any.

Comment: Why you probably miss is that prepared statements are mostly managed by the server. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-prepare.html

Comment: In fairness some libraries (such as Django) do placeholdering in code rather than the database. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Maybe (I'm not familiar with Django), but prepared statements are normally a feature of the DMBS, not of the library. That's just like the changing SQL syntax or the quotes that aren't the same everywhere (some DMBS being more laxist).

Comment: Sure. I was just explaining why it didn't occur to me. Not all SQL libraries actually use prepared statements (I suppose it's down to the driver). Anyway, problem solved, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `$1` instead of `?`:-

```
err = database.QueryRow("SELECT id from things where thing = $1", thingname).Scan(&id)
```