# Why does the gorm postgresql throws pq: syntax error at or near ")"?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

```
SELECT_QUERY = `SELECT * FROM events WHERE c_id = ? AND start_time > ? and
                                    end_time < ?`

query := sr.db.Raw(SELECT_QUERY, request.GetCId(), startTime, endTime)

    var v = request.GetVIds()
    if len(v) > 0 {
        query = query.Where(` v_id IN (?) `, v)
    } //Only this block introduces first ) after end_time

var c = request.GetStatus().String()
    if len(c) > 0 {
        query = query.Where( " status = ? ", c) // this introduces the other opening brace //after AND
    }
```

Following is the query generated and found in logs

```
 SELECT * FROM events WHERE c_id = 1 AND start_time > '2020-04-16 18:42:00' and
                                        end_time < '2020-04-16 18:45:50' ) AND ( v_id IN (1,2)) AND ( status = 'STATUS_MIDDLE_CLASS'  ORDER BY  start_time DESC  LIMIT 5 OFFSET 1
```

The other solution in stackoverflow and internet article doesn't help.

PS: Is it because I mix db.Raw( ) and query.Where() ?

Comment: Which version of gorm are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't my SQL placeholders being replaced (using Go pq)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577855/why-arent-my-sql-placeholders-being-replaced-using-go-pq)

Comment: [Postgres doesn't use question marks as placeholders](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-prepare.html). Use $1, $2, etc. instead.

Comment: Where is order and limit  adding code ?

Comment: "Is it because I mix db.Raw( ) and query.Where() ?" I believe this is the case. I don't think Gorm supports combining raw queries with the fluent query builder.

Answer (score 1):

Changing ? to $1 doesn't fix the issue.

Basically a few things fixed the issue.

1) Mixing `Raw` and `query.Where` was one issue.

After making the `Raw` query to `sr.db.Where`

2)

```
SELECT_QUERY = `SELECT * FROM events WHERE c_id = ? AND start_time > ? and
                                    end_time < ?`
```

already has `select * from`. And then using `query := sr.db.Raw(SELECT_QUERY, request.GetCId(), startTime, endTime)` introduces nested `select *.`

So, changed SELECT_QUERY as follows

```
SELECT_QUERY = `events WHERE c_id = ? AND start_time > ? and
                                    end_time < ?`
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to the error which I received when I tried to add a timestamp filed in Go/Gorm solution with PostgreSQL equivalent to `default: now()` which is `default: time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)`

I received the error because I use AutoMigrate() to create the tables in PostgreSQL.  The one problem I found is when trying to use the default value of a function instead of a string (which one can use for a fixed timestamp).

So I had to go into **DataGrid** (since I use **JetBrains**, but you can use any PostgreSQL admin tool like **pgAdmin**) and manually add the timestamp field with default of `now()` or merely update the existing field to add the default of `now()`.  Then the error goes away when doing your next build in Go.